# Consumir WebService en SQL Server

Tags: php, sql-server, webservice, stored-procedure, soap

Quiero consumir un `Web-Service` con un procedimiento desde `SQL Server`.

el `Web Service` esta echo en `PHP` usando `SOAP`

Para consumir mi `WB` desde `PHP` utilizo lo siguiente

```html
<pre>
<?php
 
    require_once('src/lib/nusoap.php');
     
    $cliente = new nusoap_client('http://localhost/Correo/enviarCorreo_WS.php');
    //print_r($cliente);
     
    $datos_correo_entrada = array( "datos_correo_entrada" => array(    
                                                                    'emisor'    => "correo@ejemplo.com",
                                                                    'contrasenia'     => "ejemplo1",
                                                                    'destinatarios'  => "soldier@gmail.com",
                                                                    'asunto'   => 'Esto es un ejemplo',
                                                                    'cuerpo'   => 'Texto del mensaje')
                                                                    );
 
    $resultado = $cliente->call('enviar_correo',$datos_correo_entrada);
     
    print_r($resultado);
     
?>
</pre>
```

Mediante ese código envió los parámetros que recibe el WB.

se puede usar desde un procedimiento en `SQL Server` y como.

Código del WS : este codigo ejecuta una función que se encuentra en el archivo `funciones.php`, la función se llama `enviar_correo` el archivo se llama `enviarCorreo_WS.php?`

```html
<?php
 // incluimos la libreria ó toolkit nusoap que descargamos previamente
 require_once('src/lib/nusoap.php');

 include 'funciones.php';

 // Vamos a crear la instancia del servidor.
 $server = new nusoap_server();

 // Inicializamos el soporte WSDL
 $server->configureWSDL('WebService Envio de Correo', 'urn:mi_ws');


 // Parametros de entrada
 $server->wsdl->addComplexType(  'datos_correo_entrada', 
                                 'complexType', 
                                 'struct', 
                                 'all', 
                                 '',
                                 array('emisor'   => array('name' => 'emisor','type' => 'xsd:string'),
                                       'contrasenia'    => array('name' => 'contrasenia','type' => 'xsd:string'),
                                       'destinatarios' => array('name' => 'destinatarios','type' => 'xsd:string'),
                                       'asunto'  => array('name' => 'asunto','type' => 'xsd:string'),
                                      'cuerpo'  => array('name' => 'cuerpo','type' => 'xsd:string'))
 );
 // Parametros de Salida
 $server->wsdl->addComplexType(  'datos_correo_salidad', 
                                 'complexType', 
                                 'struct', 
                                 'all', 
                                 '',
                                 array('mensaje'   => array('name' => 'mensaje','type' => 'xsd:string'))
 );

 $server->register(  'enviar_correo', // nombre del metodo o funcion
                    array('datos_correo_entrada' => 'tns:datos_correo_entrada'), // parametros de entrada
                    array('return' => 'tns:datos_correo_salidad'), // parametros de salida
                    'urn:mi_ws', // namespace
                    'urn:hellowsdl2#enviar_correo', // soapaction debe ir asociado al nombre del metodo
                    'rpc', // style
                    'encoded', // use
                    'La siguiente funcion recibe los parametros del correo y envia los datos' // documentation
 );

 $HTTP_RAW_POST_DATA = isset($HTTP_RAW_POST_DATA) ? $HTTP_RAW_POST_DATA : '';
 $server->service($HTTP_RAW_POST_DATA);
 
?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Lo que indicas es posible, utilizando Procedimientos almacenados para automatización OLE por medio de ejecuciones a métodos de este tipo. [OLE Automation Stored Procedures (Transact-SQL)](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-stored-procedures/ole-automation-stored-procedures-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017)

Te dejo un script de ejemplo:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE CALLWEBSERVICE(@Para1 ,@Para2)
AS
BEGIN
    Declare @Object as Int;
    Declare @ResponseText as Varchar(8000);

    Exec sp_OACreate 'MSXML2.XMLHTTP', @Object OUT;
    Exec sp_OAMethod @Object, 'open', NULL, 'get', 'http://url_del_servicio','false'
    Exec sp_OAMethod @Object, 'send'
    Exec sp_OAMethod @Object, 'responseText', @ResponseText OUTPUT
    Select @ResponseText
    Exec sp_OADestroy @Object
END
```

Comment: Utilizando esa estructura como quedaría mi WB resibe 5 parámetros cuales están en un arreglo, los cuales se utilizan para la función  enviar_correo agrego el código del WB

Comment: agregue el arriba el código de mi WS espero me puedas ayudar